# How to change every specific value in an array to another value? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How can I change every specific value within an array to another specific value? My function splits a string into an array, and if a specific index == "T" it's supposed to change that value to "U", join the values in the array, and return the result. But the value "T" isn't changing within the array as I loop through it. What am I doing wrong?

```
function DNAtoRNA(dna) {

let array = dna.split();
let rna = "";

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if(array[i] == 'T') {
    a[i] = 'U';
  }
  }
rna = array.join();
return rna;
}
```

Example input = "ATFT", output = "AUFU"

Comment: You're using `a[i] = 'U';` instead of `array[i] = 'U';`

Comment: Although there are better solutions to do that, your problem is **a[i]** should be **array[i]**

Comment: The real reason this doesn't work is because you are using `dna.split()`, and using `.split()` without a parameter will simply wrap the original string into an array. So your `array` contains `["ATFT"]`, whose only element isn't equal to `'T'`.